# Send parameter to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation, error-handling

I have a form for creating a ticket, which needs an id of a project. This works but not when it comes to validation. If validation won't pass 'render :new' is executed and the project_id doesn't come with it.

I have tried 'redirect_to new_ticket_path(:project_id => params[:ticket][:project_id]) which renders the form again, but the error messages won't show up so it seems that I need to use 'render :new'.

How can I pass the project_id back to the form or reach project_id from the form without passing it?

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @id = params[:project_id]
  @project = Project.find(@id)
end

def create
  @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

  if @ticket.save
    redirect_to @ticket
      else
    render :new <--- will render without the project_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will render just the view for 'new', but will not run the controller action.  You'd need to set up your variables for the 'new' view in your 'create' action.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

> Using render with :action is a frequent source of confusion for Rails
>   newcomers. The specified action is used to determine which view to
>   render, but Rails does not run any of the code for that action in the
>   controller. Any instance variables that you require in the view must
>   be set up in the current action before calling render.

The easiest way around this is to change 'new':

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new(:project_id => params[:project_id])
end
```

and change any references to @project in your 'new' form to @ticket.project.  At that point, you shouldn't have to add anything to your 'create' action as long as your form includes a hidden field for the ticket's project id.

Comment: Tried your solution but get this error: "undefined method `project' for #<Ticket:0x007f9e74e0a550>"... referring to -> "<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @ticket.project.id %>"

Comment: Well, with names like Ticket, Project, and project_id I assumed that would be the name.  Your Ticket must have a 'belongs_to :project' or similar, right?  You would need to use the name of the relation.

Comment: sorry, it was my first comment and didn't realize hitting return would post it...

Comment: Get what you're after now. But that relation doesn't exist before the ticket is created. In :create I tie the ticket with the project here: @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket].merge(:user_id => current_user.id)) <- params[:ticket][:project_id]

Comment: In 'new', you're creating but not saving the Ticket.  However, you can still assign the Project.  Alternatively, you can add the '@project' setup code from 'new' to 'create' just above the call to render.  Since the '@ticket' can already store the project reference, however, there really isn't a need to have duplicated code like that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this working (and I would do this anyway) is to nest the task resource under projects. That way you will always have project_id available in params.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

The urls will look like `projects/123/tasks/new` etc. Take a look at `rake routes`.

Answer (score 0):

Write project id into a hidden field in your form and you will okay. And don't forget to initialize `@id` in your create action

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @id = params[:project_id]
  @project = Project.find(@id)
end

def create
  @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
  @id = params[:project_id] # but make sure it is under this key in params
  if @ticket.save
    redirect_to @ticket
      else
    render :new <--- will render without the project_id
  end
end
```

and in the form add

```
<%= hidden_field :project_id, '', value: @id %>
```

Comment: I already have an hidden field with the project_id, but when I render the form after errors I don't have it anymore.

Comment: Suppose you are using your `@id` variable in the form, right? You must initialize it within your create action `@id = params[:project_id]` (or wherever it is in the params hash)

Comment: Yes, I do this already. The problem is that when I render :new again after errors, project_id won't follow.

Comment: Everything with `@id = params[:project_id]` within your create action ?

Comment: Sorry, I do now quite follow?

Comment: Thanks. Ok, now the errors is shown as supposed. But when I try to submit the form the second time (after render :new) the project_id is missing :(

Comment: This is because when rendering :new the id won't follow.

Comment: Then try `<input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<%= @id %>" />`

Comment: Writing for the third time already: you have to put `@id = params[:project_id]` line inside CREATE action

Comment: I have "@id = params[:project_id]" inside CREATE... will try the last one now.

Comment: Tried it with the same result. A shady thing here is that after render :new the querystring is not longer /tickets/new but /tickets ???

Comment: Are you putting your hidden field inside your form? Within the form tag?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use:

```
 flash[:alert] = @ticket.errors.inspect
 redirect_to new_ticket_path(:project_id => params[:ticket][:project_id])
```

Comment: This shows me the errors in a flash message, which is not what I want.